Read and Delivered Status Database Design for group chat application
I am building a group chat application. I want to handle the read receipts in most efficient way. Currently I am unable to use another services like redis etc. I just have supabase as backend and react as frontend.
Requiredment
Like whatsapp ticks

Does everyone read my message (double blue tick)
Does every one delivered message (double grey tick)
Does no one read message (single tick)

Also want to track seen and delivery time
My current database is
User table
User {
  id: int
  created_at: time
}

GroupMember table
GroupMember {
  id: int
  user_id: *User.id*
  created_at: time
}

Message table
Message {
  id: int
  message: text
  send_by: *GroupMember.id*
  created_at: time
}

Read Status table
Status{
  id: int
  message_id: *Message.id*
  group_member_id: *GroupMember.id*
  read_at: time
  delivered_at: time
}

While creating message I added a trigger to create rows in read_status table for each group member
Then I can easily track the read details
My concern is about the performence
If there is a lot of member in group does it affect creating that much rows on sending a message. Also fetching the unread message count
Note: I only need the read and delivered time when user click info button and select status
Suggest any good solution for a good performence
I am expecting an answer with any of these

A good databse design to manage this
Any way to optmization in code or function excecution
Or any other good solution

